# Socket code fails when compiled with -O flag

Tags: c, sockets, polling

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with gcc version 5.4.0.  I have a fairly simple sockets example in C that fails when I compile with optimization (-O) (it works with no optimization).  I trimmed my original code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>

int main() {
    struct addrinfo *ai, hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    getaddrinfo(NULL, "7471", &hints, &ai);

    int listen_fd = socket(ai->ai_family, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(listen_fd, ai->ai_addr, ai->ai_addrlen);
    freeaddrinfo(ai);

    listen(listen_fd, 128);

    struct pollfd fds;
    fds.fd = listen_fd;
    fds.events = POLLIN;
    poll(&fds, -1, -1);
}
```

The compiler has problems with the call to poll().  The warning message is

```
in function ‘poll’,
    inlined from ‘main’ at simplecode.c:25:5:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/poll2.h:43:9: warning: call to ‘__poll_chk_warn’ declared with attribute warning: poll called with fds buffer too small file nfds entries
  return __poll_chk_warn (__fds, __nfds, __timeout, __bos (__fds));
```

The actual runtime error is longer, but starts with:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./simplecode terminated
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *`nfds_t` -  An **unsigned integer type** used for the number of file descriptors.* Guess what it does with `-1`:D

Comment: You aren't checking the return code from `getaddrinfo`

Comment: Yes, I eliminated the return value check to make the code smaller for this discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man 2 poll`

> int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
>
> The caller should specify the number of items in the fds array in
>   nfds.

So, your `poll(&fds, -1, -1)` should be `poll(&fds, 1, -1)`

Edit:
You also should check the return values of your function calls.
They might return a value which indicates an error (mostly `-1`) and set errno.

Comment: Thank you.  Setting nfds to 1 solved it.  I would not have expected a compiler warning from that....